# Контент появляется раньше прелоадер. В чем причина?

Tags: javascript, html

html разметка прелоадер стоит раньше всего контента. Скрипт тоже.
Проверяла на обычном шаблоне с 6 картинками и все работало. Но в полноценном лендинге возникает проблема с прелоадер.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Опубликуйте тут минимальный воспроизводимый пример с ошибкой, пожалуйста!

Comment: Первая мысль - проверьте, в какой момент запускается скрипт. Возможно не сразу, а после загрузки чего-то определенного. И вторая мысль - проверить стили. Возможно, когда запускается скрипт, стили прелоадера ещё не загружены

Answer (score -1):

Ваш preloader должен быть выше всех слоёв, например можно указать `z-index: 999999;`, как вариант еще надо указать свойство `position: fixed`.

Так же проверьте, ваш preloader должен висеть на событии onload.

```
window.onload = function(){ /* Тут удаляете свой preloader */}
```